# InfoPath: Hide view dropdown box from user

Tags: infopath

I created a client based InfoPath 2007 compatible form with multiple views in InfoPath 2010 Designer. The form contains rules to switch views as needed, so I don't want the users who fill out the form to switch views manually.

Is there a way to hide/disable the view dropdown-box in the ribbon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When designing the form on the "Page Design" tab select each view and click Properties
[image]

Then deselect "Show on the View menu when filling out this form" (yes the name of the setting is a bit odd, but that due to how it was displayed in InfoPath 2007)
[image]

Comment: This won't actually solve the problem - it will just hide the form from the change view dropdown menu. If you want to remove the option to change view completely then see the answer from George Winters.

Answer (score 4):

File --> Advanced Form Options

[image: Options Dialog in infopath 2010]

THIS is where you can hide the drop-down in the ribbon.

Comment: But that would only modify the setting for the current user, not for everyone that would use the form template.

Comment: No, this is in Designer, and hides the ribbon for the template.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. My mistake. First time I read this question, I couldn't see any images. This being the case, this is indeed the superior way to completely hide the view selection control.

Comment: +1. This should be the accepted answer. The other answer doesn't actually answer the question. Maybe the user asked the wrong question?